# Get all users from multiple roles

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to get all users given an array of `roles`. I tried this:

```
var subQueries = [];
for (var i=0; i<roles.length; i++) {
    var subquery = role.getUsers().query();
    subQueries.push(subquery)
}
var userQuery = Parse.Query.or.apply(Parse.Query, subQueries);
userQuery.find().then(function(users) {
   ...etc
}
```

but the user queries were undefined. However, it does work if I immediately use the subquery. However, I want to combine the subqueries in one single query so I can get all the users in one go.

Is this possible?

Comment: what looks like your array `roles` ?

Comment: roles is an array of Parse.Role objects